# How to sort an array of arrays in ascending order

Tags: arrays, ruby

Information in an array:

```rb
scores = %w[ScoreA ScoreB ScoreC ScoreD ScoreE ScoreF ScoreG ScoreH ScoreI ScoreJ]
```

needs to be presented in ascending order of the golf scores.

Can anyone help sorting the output in ascending order?

```rb
golf = scores.map do |score_number|
  print "Enter the score for #{score_number}:"
  [score_number, gets.to_i]
end

puts golf.sort
```

Comment: "Any tips?" is hardly a proper question. Please have a look at to ask [a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take your time to format the code properly. You can see a preview of your post in the bottom of the editing page.

Comment: @dedObed, Thank you for your input. Both are edited.

Answer (score 4):

Just use [`Array#sort`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-i-sort) with block

```
golf.sort { |a, b| a.last <=> b.last }
```

or [`Enumerable#sort_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by)

```
golf.sort_by { |a| a.last }
```

The second variant [can be shortened](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc) using `Proc`

```
golf.sort_by(&:last)
```

Comment: @ray Your edit changes the code's intention. That is too much.

Comment: You can address block as `sort_by(&:last)` with to format short in length.

Comment: @ray, I've updated my answer and added the link to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`Array#sort`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/sort) with block

```
golf.sort { |x, y| x[1] <=> y[1] }
=> [["ScoreH", 1], ["ScoreB", 3], ["ScoreD", 4], ["ScoreF", 9], ["ScoreA", 10], ["ScoreJ", 23], ["ScoreG", 45], ["ScoreC", 67], ["ScoreI", 87], ["ScoreE", 88]]
```